# Como pasar formulario a un método para validar si ya esta abierto

Tags: c#, formularios

tengo un `mdi` con varios menús que abren formularios y tengo el siguiente código:

```
private void MenuInventario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Se busca entre los forms abiertos
        Form frm = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x is FrmControlInventario);

        if (frm != null)
        {
            //Si esta minimizado la dejamos en su estado normal
            if (frm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            //subo el formulario
            frm.BringToFront();
            return;
        }

        //Se abre el formulario
        frm = new FrmControlInventario();
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();
    }
```

El menú es extenso y necesito verificar si esta abierto *(para no volver a abrir)* o minimizado *(para mostrar al centro de la pantalla)* el formulario, es por esto que quiero enviar el formulario antes de abrir al método para que realice estos pasos.

> ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

---

Ya está solucionado en respuestas. :)

Comment: Hola, Lo que quieres validar es si ya esta abierto para no abrirlo de nuevo?

Comment: Buenas         eso lo tengo claro, lo que necesito es no repetir todo ese codigo. Lo que necesito es poder enviar el formulario a un metodo para que realice el trabajo y desde ahi abrir el formulario. la idea es optimizar codigo ya que son muchos formularios que podrian abrir y hacer lo mismo por separado es un caos.

Comment: No entiendo cual formulario quieres enviar al método. Obviamente no es el que quieres abrir, porque si lo puedes enviar, es que el formulario ya está abierto. No entiendo bien lo que pides.

Comment: Antes de abrir el formulario pregunto si ya esta abierto y también si esta minimizado, eso lo quiero hacer para muchos formularios que se abren desde un mdi, la idea es no repetir eso en cada click al abrir los formularios. Por eso necesito enviar el formulario(nombre) y validar... la idea es optimizar codigo

Comment: se puede generalizar.. te tiro ideas, el codigo depende mucho de que funcionalidad de acceso tenes. Y ademas hay varias maneras. A mi me gusta mantener una clase aparte para estas cosas, no depender de la coleccion de hijos del form principal, pero todo es viable. Vas a necesitar saber que boton fue apretado (obviamente). Capaz el boton pueda tener en el tag el nombre del form que tiene que abrir? Tu evento click deberia ser generico a todos los botones. El evento tiene que chequear si ese form en particula esta abierto (todos heredan de winform o mdichild) y manejarte con esa info.

Comment: Es imposible responder mas que esto, porque no hay mas informacion, y no es un codigo tan trivial como parece.

Comment: Si esa es una respuesta valida, quitala de la pregunta y ponela como respuesta, es algo totalmente valido en el sitio y asi debe hacerse. Mas alla de eso, podrias explicar porque el gettype anda en este caso? Todos tus formularios MDI no son de typo mdichild? entonces como sabe cual es el que estas pasando?

Comment: el comentario de respuesta tiene mas de 600 caracteres. no puedo colocarlo como comentario...alguna otra forma?

Comment: @Marcelostg las respuestas van en la seccion respuesta, no en la seccion comentario. Es perfectamente valido responder tu propia pregunta.

Comment: @Marcelostg como te dicen otros usuarios, por favor, mueve la respuesta a la sección de respuestas en lugar de dejarla en la pregunta. Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré la respuesta:

```
private void AbreFormulario(Type formType)
    {
        //Se localiza el formulario buscandolo entre los forms abiertos 
        Form frm = this.MdiChildren.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetType() == formType);

        if (frm != null)
        {
            //Si la instancia esta minimizada la dejamos en su estado normal
            if (frm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            //Si la instancia existe la pongo en primer plano
            frm.BringToFront();
            return;
        }

        //Se abre el form
        frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
        frm.MdiParent = this;
        frm.Show();
    }
```

y llamo a los formularios así:

```
private void MenuInventario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AbreFormulario(typeof(FrmControlInventario));
}
```

Gracias a todos por su ayuda.